# HybridAuth - continue script after authentication and get result

Tags: oauth, hybridauth

I have a facebook login function where I instantiate Hybrid_Auth and the user is authenticated:

```
    $oauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

//go to facebook
     $provider = $oauth->authenticate('Facebook');

//continue script?
     $profile = $provider->getUserProfile();

     die(var_dump($profile));
```

(as in the example here (configuration & usage) [hybridauth.github.io/hybridauth/userguide](https://hybridauth.github.io/hybridauth/userguide/IDProvider_info_Facebook.html) )

But how is the script supposed to continue where it left off, after the

"`->authenticate('Facebook')"`?

In all the examples I have seen, a large part seems to be implicit information that is left out, and not being explained.

On "->authenticate", the user is redirected to facebook and then redirected back to a specific url. I have specified a redirect URI in facebook developers, like:

```
https://myweb.com/fbauth/authenticate?hauth.done=Facebook
```

and I have a "base_url" in the config array, which I guess is the url that the user returns to after login. I pointed it to the same function where I do the authentication:

```
'base_url' => 'https://myweb.com/fbauth/authenticate',
```

So after authentication the function starts again from the beginning, and if it has the "authenticate" slug, I try to run: `Hybrid_Endpoint::process();` but this results in a 404. But I would rather have resumed from after the authentication so I can get the result of `$profile`. How is this supposed to be handled, and how can I get the result? I use Laravel by the way.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with version 3. The documentation is incredibly lacking.
Did you find a solution?